# Windows Phone 7 - Add alarm to default app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, alarm

I suspect the answer to this is no, but is it possible to programmatically add alarms into the default alarm app on Windows Phone 7?

I'm hoping to avoid building a section of my app just to recreate the functionality in the existing app!

Answer (score 0):

You can set alarms on the phone without having to use code of your own by using the Phone.scheduler namespace and initializing a new alarm instance.

Comment: I'm aware of the ability to create alarms via this method. The issue is that you then have to create a screen in your app to manage said alarms as they aren't added to the default alarm app.

Comment: Sorry for not having understood your need. you cannot manage your alarms through the default app. you will have to take the trouble of creating your own page to do the same